# How to import a .xls file that when opened in notepad is all html? vb.net

Tags: html, vb.net, import, xls

I have a .xls file that is downloaded from an asp.net website.  I need to import the data from the file into access database using vb.net.  If you open the xls file in notepad it is all html. Trying to bring the data in like it is a normal excel file doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with OLEDB actually, - you specify that it is HTML in the extended properties, E.g.

```
Dim oleExcelConnection As OleDbConnection

sConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Test.xls;Extended Properties=""HTML Import;IMEX=1"""

oleExcelConnection = New OleDbConnection(sConnection)
oleExcelConnection.Open()

...

oleExcelConnection.close()
```

It's a while since I tried this and it worked okay but I choose to force the files to .xlsx in the final implementation. I can't remember why exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to open it in excel first and save it in the file format you are trying to use. The file is HTML, it's not in an excel format. The website is using a trick to have the browser open excel with the returned HTML by setting the content-type to application/vnd.ms-excel and the file extension to .xls. The browser will launch excel with the html file in most cases. Excel will see the file is not in the right format but will allow the user to open and import it.

Comment: Unfortunately that will not work as it will be over the users head and defeating the purpose of the application.

Comment: I would use LinToXml (System.Xml.Linq) to parse the file then, then use whatever to import it to access. Can you elaborate more on your process more? Is the application going to be run by the user? How are you planning to update an access database? Automation? Can you modify the website?